# How do I read a file located in a same folder where my page resides in in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I read a file located in a same folder where my page resides in in ASP.NET (C#)?
I have a page called mypage.aspx and I'm trying to read in a file called foo.txt residing in a same directory as this page.

Is there a way to open that file for reading with `File.OpenRead()`?
Providing a relative path like `File.OpenRead("foo.txt")` fails b/c of the location of the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be something like

```
File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("foo.txt"));
```

Comment: Should be `File.OpenRead(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("foo.txt"));`

Comment: @Alex - if you're in the context of a page code behind, the syntax Matten used will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should try `File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("foo.txt"))`.

If `MapPath` doesn't expand/can't find the proper path at this point then try it while specifying the relative path to the page in question starting from the sites virtual root (using the tilde (`~`) at the beginning of the string to indicate this), i.e. `File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("~/path/foo.txt"))`

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET the folder is really IIS's folder which is typically in C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\ etc.

What you will need to do is use either

```
Server.MapPath("TheFileName").
```

Or get the PhysicalApplicationPath from the Request using

```
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```

or

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath
```

and go from the Request and then go from there

Answer (score 1):

You can use a label message or textbox in the aspx page and you can display the file in that by using the below code, I had used a label message wit `lblDisplay ID`.

```
lblDisplay.Text = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("Give the path here"));
```